# Placing and aligning a div on another div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've been going mad trying to apply a div over another div that contains an image. The div should include a simple HTML link just like in this picture:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39682698/Fraud-Fighter2.png

unfortunately when the page renders the image the URL is not centered on the image, as seen on the live site here:

http://us.aktive.me/maintenance/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ThreatMetrix Maintenance Page</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="apDiv1"><a href="http://threatmetrix.com/support">http://threatmetrix.com/support</a></div>
    <div id="image"><img src="fraud-fighter.png" width="977" height="750" alt="ThreatMetrix Maintenance Page" /></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color: #3fa9f5;
    /*background-image:url(fraud-fighter.png);*/
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-position:top;
    font-size : 1.5em;
    font-family : Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a:link     { background-color: transparent; color:#f28a1a}
a:visited  { background-color: transparent; color:#f28a1a}
a:active   { background-color: transparent; position:relative}
a:hover    { background-color: transparent; color:#cb7518}
a.noformat { text-decoration: none; color: #121212}

#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

#apDiv1 {
    margin-top: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
}

#image {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

a million thanks in advance to anyone that can help me :)
-Dean

Answer (score 0):

Set css as below.

```
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 250px;
}
```

if you want in `%`

```
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 31%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center your DIV, you can do something like this:

```
width:400px; left:50%; margin-left: -200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You #apDiv1 needs to be the same width as your container div.

Answer (score 0):

NOw define your `ID` `#apDiv1` `left 50%` and `margin-left` according to your design

**as like this**

```
#apDiv1 {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -185px;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**2nd method is this**

**now define** Your `ID` `#apDiv1` `left:0` and `right:0;`

```
#apDiv1{
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the apDiv1 css to below

```
#apDiv1 {
margin-top: 242px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#apDiv1 {
        width:inherit;
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute;
        top:240px;
}
```